# Rails SSL Requirement plugin -- shouldn't it check to see if you're in production mode before redirecting to https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

[Take a look at the ssl_requirement plugin.](http://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement/tree/master/lib/ssl_requirement.rb)

Shouldn't it check to see if you're in production mode?  We're seeing a redirect to https in development mode, which seems odd.  Or is that the normal behavior for the plugin?  I thought it behaved differently in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess they believe that you should probably be using HTTPS (perhaps with a self-signed certificate) in development mode. If that's not the desired behaviour, there's nothing stopping you from special casing SSL behaviour in the development environment yourself:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  ssl_required :update unless Rails.env.development?
end
```

Comment: I use ssl_required in development all the time and in test mode, to make sure that my ssl redirects are indeed working.

I have found the easiest way around this is to use Nginx with ssl proxied to a thin server.

Answer (score 4):

```
  def ssl_required?
    return false if local_request? || RAILS_ENV == 'test' || RAILS_ENV == 'development'
    super
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be testing that your application redirects to https during sensitive stages.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much point in requiring SSL in the development environment.

You can stub out the plugins **ssl_required?** method using Rails' built in mocking facilities.

Under your application root directory create a file test/mocks/development/application.rb

```
require 'controllers/application_controller'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def ssl_required?
    false
  end
end
```

This way SSL is never required in the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

actually, redirect over https is a webserver responsibility. Add extra request hash verification per each request into Rails is a overhead IMHO. I wrote nginx [config](https://gist.github.com/711913), which include following rewrite:

rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;